# how to copy files using ssh under the key-based [pem} configuration

Tags: ssh

i have a server which is access remote connection only with  SSH key auth
i have a key which is stored in my home directory with .pem extension
but when im trying to copy file using the scp command
scp /home/myfilewhichiwannatocopy core@54.32.14.156:/home/core  the server asks for password but i don't have it ( btw normal connection using the ssh -i /.ssh/mg.service.pem core@54.32.14.156 fully works) and how to make the scp command for using the key auth?

Answer (score 0):

```
  scp -i /path/to/key.pem somefile.txt user@<machine>:/path
```

Might I also add, you can consult the man pages https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp